# how could I gain a class address from it's base in multiple-inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, base-class, ambiguous, name-lookup

I used a third-part library in my company. In it, Some classes I need is defined like this:

```
class A
{};

class B : public A
{};

class C : public A
{};

class Foo
 : public B
 , public C
 , public A
{};
```

And here, I need to gain offsets between Foo and all it's base classes.
so I code like this:

```
int main()
{

    Foo* f = new Foo();

    int_ptr ptrb = ((B*)(Foo*)0x1) - 0x1;
    int_ptr ptrc = ((C*)(Foo*)0x1) - 0x1;

    int_ptr ptra = ((A*)(Foo*)0x1) - 0x1;     // error
    A *ptr = (A*)(Foo*)f;     // error

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

in VC2010 and VC2012, it's all okay.

but in GCC 4.7.3, there will be a "Ambiguous base" compile-error.

I may not modify any code of the declaration.
How could I gain the offset between Foo and the last "public A" ?

Comment: Is a Foo object really supposed to contain 3 instances of A? In many cases, what’s really needed is 1 shared instance, so you’d use a virtual base class.

Comment: If you want the offset to then invoke a method, why not invoke the method directly?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. In fact, in my project, we used a 3rd-part library. In the library there are some COM-interfaces and some classes implement them. If there is a class implement some interfaces, I need to show distance from each interface to it's class. But unfortunately I cannot modify any code of that library.

Comment: retag: this is an inherently ambiguous inheritance, so removing compiler-specific tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be simplified:

```
class A
{};

class B : public A
{};

class Foo
 : public B
 , public A
{};
```

Here the `Foo` class has two `A` base classes

- one indirect base class `A` named `Foo::B::A`
- **a direct base class `A` that you cannot name in C++**

You will be able get the `B::A` base class subobject of a `Foo` object:

```
Foo f;
B &b = f;
A &a = b;
```

but not the other `A` impossible-to-name base class subobject.

You created an **ambiguous inheritance** situation.

**Conclusion**: do not do that.

Also: I really have no idea what you were really trying to do.

Comment: Well, thanks.It seems that I could only reflect interface A by using ((A*)(B*)(Foo*)0x1)

Comment: Here I need to reflect all interfaces implemented by a class, but these classes are coded by another group. so I was beset that there is a class like Foo implement three interfaces like ABC...

Comment: The `A` interface is implemented twice by `Foo`? What for?

Comment: I also don't know why they did it... May be a mistake?